# Best Practices Database Architecture for parallel computing with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, architecture, fork

i'm developing a tool which connects to nodes and fetches their connection data with PHP.

The architecture I'm using is a Worker which forks itself in the constructor as many times as nodes has to be taken care of, connects to the Nodes and retrieves their connection data(*about 5 fields with relatively short strings and big integers*).

The problem i'm facing is that the database connection drops when a distinct childworker finished his work. *An approach would be to establish a new mysql connection each time a child wants to access the database. Is this a good practice to do so?*

To grant database access I implemented a singleton-like database class but in fact the class does not use one connection as intended, rather using a mysql connection for each childworker. (*i read about that phenomenon "ShareNothing" or anything like this*)

This is crucial - I heard of the mysql connection limit which should be around 100 by default. 
While I'm currently maintaining about 60 nodes the amount of nodes could rise in the next very few months. The corporation i'm currently working at is very restrictive when it comes to use a variety of components, so gearman is not an option.

I'm at a point where I'm lacking of ideas.
How should I design the database access to grant scalability for a rising amount of nodes?

**Edit:** The Application is running via PHP CLI. The worker start their run function which contains a sequence of actions surrounded by a while-loop. 
The sequence is built like this (pseudocode INC):

```
while(allowedToRun())
if(isConnectionStillOpen())
fetchDataFromNodes()
enterIdleRoutine
else
exit
```

So the application is intended to run for a indefinite span of time

Comment: it moved to 151 as of  mysql 5.1.15 but its configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection drops either because you are dropping them or **you are starting a new connection every time a new php page is loaded** (this is the default behavior of php way of programing, if you need something more sophisticated you should consider move to java or other midleware programing language).

BTW from the php manual

> The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling mysql_close().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

---

This is not related with the number of connections opened, but you should learn about transactions, to control the concurrent access:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

also do a reading on the table lock is also a good idea

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the fact that the application is running via the PHP commandline Interface(CLI) - so the explanation that the connection drops because of reloading the page is not suitable.

Comment: @Ben every time the script ends the connection is closed, I included the link to the php manual and a quotation.

Comment: the script is not ending in that way, only a forked child exits. the other childs are still running but their further operations fail because of no active link to the db

Comment: @Ben does each child opens it's own connection? or they share the same connection?

Comment: they do share the same connection through a database class

Comment: @Ben well, then you have your answer, read my quotation from the php manual. You will need to rewrite the the connection class to make sure each child uses it's own connection.